# Tricky differential equation: (y'/y)'=y^2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation defined on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$: $$(y'/y)'=y^2 $$

where we impose $y>0$ for all positive $x$ and $y$ does not explode as we approach $x=0$.

I have found the solution $y=\frac{a}{\sinh(ax+b)}$ for integration constants $a,b$, but I'm having some trouble proving it is the unique solution.

If we try $y=1/z(x)$ we get $$1-(z')^2+z*z''=0$$ Still complicated. We could even try $y=a/\sinh(z(x))$, which gives after some manipulation:

$$0.5 \sinh(2z)z'-z^2=-a^2$$

and we would could try to prove $z= a$.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you put $y(x)=e^{z(x)}$ you get $z''=e^{2z}$, if this is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $2y'/y$ to get
$$
\left(\left(\frac{y'}y\right)^2\right)'=(y^2)'\implies y'^2=y^4+Ay^2
$$
Now you got to solve
$$
\int\frac{dy}{y\sqrt{A+y^2}}=\pm t+B
$$
where indeed for $A>0$ the substitution $y=\sqrt{A}\sinh(z)$ appears quite natural.

Comment: Then try $y=\sqrt{-A}\cosh(z)$, this should follow similar lines.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left (\frac {y'}{y} \right )'=y^2$$
It's a nice equation.
$$\frac {d}{dy}\left (\frac {y'}{y} \right )\frac {dy}{dx}=y^2$$
$$y'\frac {d}{dy}\left (\frac {y'}{y} \right )=y^2$$
$$\frac {y'}{y} {d}\left (\frac {y'}{y} \right )=y dy$$
Integration :
$$ \left(\frac {y'}{y} \right )^2=y^2+K$$
$$ \left( {y'} \right )^2=y^2(y^2+K)$$
$$  {y'}  = \pm y \sqrt {y^2+K}$$
It's also related to Bernouilli's equation.